# arraylist java counting runs of integers

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am new to java and array lists. I am supposed to sort populate an array full of random integers, then if there is a run (multiples of the same number in a row), put ( ) around that run. 
So if the random list is:

2 3 4 5 5 5 5 6  7 7 9

2 3 4 (5 5 5 5) 6 (7 7) 9

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

class Run {
  public static void main (String [] args){

    Scanner m = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter length wanted: ");
    int len = m.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter max number wanted: ");
    int max = m.nextInt();
    max = max -1;

   int[] x = new int[len]; 
   ArrayList<String> y = new ArrayList<String>();

   //Filling x with random numbers
   for(int i = 0; i<len; i++){

    x[i] = ((int)(Math.random()*max)+1); 

   }

   System.out.println("Orginal Array: " + Arrays.toString(x));


   for(int i = 0; i<=len-1; i++){
     if(x[i] == x[i++]){ //I just don't know how I am exactly supposed to sort this

     }else{

     }

  }
   //Array List with ()
   System.out.println("Runs labeled Array: " + y);

  }
}
```

Comment: just use `Collections.sort(yourList);`

Comment: @JigarJoshi It's probably a homework assignment.

Comment: as long as teacher doesn't specify, you could be smart ;)

Answer (score 0):

use [`Collections.sort(yourList)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) to sort your ArrayList.

If you dont wanna use API methods.

try :

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size(); i++){
            for(int j=i+1; j<list.size(); j++){
                if(list.get(i)>list.get(j)){
                    temp = list.get(i);
                    list.set(i,list.get(j));
                    list.set(j, temp);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's *probably* a homework assignment (i.e. he can't use that). But yes, this would be the appropriate way to do it in general.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a String to display the final output. Also, don't go out of the array.
Try Something like this:

```
x = Collections.sort(x);
String s = "";
boolean b;
for(int i = 0; i<=len-1; i++){
 if(x[i] == x[i+1]){
   s+=" ("+i+" ";
   b = true;
 }else{
   if(b == true){
      s+=i+") ";
      b = false;
   }
   s+=i + " ";
 }

}
```

Comment: This hasn't been tested, by the way.